# Swift error cannot invoke '+' with an argument list of type '($T28, $T32)'

Tags: swift

I'm getting a strange error that I can't help but think is a compiler error. In Swift, in either a Playground or in an iOS app, if I do the following...

```
let array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let sum = array[0] + array[1] + array[2] + array[3] + array[4] + array[5]
```

...I get the following compiler error.

```
cannot invoke '+' with an argument list of type '($T28, $T32)'
```

Just for grins, I changed that to an array of strings and I get the same. However, if I just add the first five values, no error. Leaving aside the fact that this is not the best way to sum up these numbers, how is this not a compiler error?

And if it isn't a compiler error, why isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you try to create an Integer Array:

```
let array:[Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I had the same issue. I guess to compiler did not recognize the type of your array values.

If you use:

```
let sum = Int(array[0]) + Int(array[1]) + Int(array[2]) + Int(array[3]) + Int(array[4]) + Int(array[5])
```

it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for this. Interesting way to force it. I wish there was a way to accept both answers since both confirm my question that this is a compiler error.

Comment: This Q&A has more on the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088184/could-not-find-member-subscript/26088212?noredirect=1#comment40880289_26088212